# python to_date wrong values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Command:

```
dataframe.date.head()
```

Result:

```
0    12-Jun-98
1     7-Aug-2005
2    28-Aug-66
3    11-Sep-1954
4     9-Oct-66
5     NaN
```

Command:

```
pd.to_date(dataframe.date.head())
```

Result:

```
0    1998-06-12 00:00:00
1    2005-08-07 00:00:00
2    2066-08-28 00:00:00
3    1954-09-11 00:00:00
4    2066-10-09 00:00:00
5    NaN
```

I don't want to get 2066 it should be 1966, what to do?

**The year range supposed to be from 1920 to 2017. The dataframe contains Null values**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substract `100` years if [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) is more as `2017`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].mask(df['date'].dt.year > 2017, 
                             df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(100, unit='Y'))
print (df)

                 date
0 1998-06-12 00:00:00
1 2005-08-07 00:00:00
2 1966-08-28 18:00:00
3 1954-09-11 00:00:00
4 1966-10-09 18:00:00
```

Comment: but now there's 1908 instead of 2008 the range supposed to be from (1920-2017)

Comment: I am on phone only, so untested. But try change `df['date'].str[-3] == '-'` to `(df['date'].str[-3] == '-') & ( df['date'].str[-2:].astype(int) > 19)`

Comment: Now I am on phone only, please give me some time aroud one hour and then I believe I get solution. Thanks.

Comment: Finally I find simplier solution, please check edited answer.

Comment: it looks better but i get this (`AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`)

Comment: My solution is completly changed, first create dayrtimes and then remove 100 days by condition.

Comment: Please check the picture i uploaded and the result for index 0

Comment: I see it :( What is your pandas version? `print(pd.show_versions())` ? Last is pandas 21.0. And if use only `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` first date is parsed wrong?